# Is there a way to have multiple rectangles displayed at the same time using visual.Rect in PsychoPy?

Tags: psychopy

I'm trying to create stimuli that consist of 100 small lines in the centre of the screen, with orientations sampled from a Gaussian distribution (please see the image link below):

[Orientation stimuli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbmz7.png)

I've managed to achieve something that almost fits the bill, but this code only works in isolation:

```
from psychopy import visual, core, event
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random

import random

Lines = visual.Rect(
win=win, name='Lines',
width=(0.015, 0.0025)[0], height=(0.015, 0.0025)[1],
lineWidth=1, lineColor=[1,1,1], lineColorSpace='rgb',
fillColor=[1,1,1], fillColorSpace='rgb',
opacity=1, depth=-2.0, interpolate=True)

lines_hpos = np.random.uniform(-0.49,0.49,100)
mu = 315
sigma = 15

for i in range(100):

Lines.pos = [lines_hpos[i],np.random.uniform(-0.49,0.49)]
Lines.ori = random.gauss(mu, sigma)
```

I've tried to manipulate this code so that I can integrate it into the full experiment I'm designing in PsychoPy's experiment builder. I run the below code in the experiment builder's coding window calling 'gdist' and 'loc' as values for the 'Orientation' and 'Position' of the rectangles, respectively:

```
import random
gdist =[]
loc = []
lines_hpos = np.random.uniform(-0.49,0.49,100)
mu = 90
sigma = 20

for i in range(100):
    
    rloc = [lines_hpos[i],np.random.uniform(-0.49,0.49)]
    loc.append(rloc)
    
    gauss = random.gauss(mu, sigma)
    gdist.append(gauss)
```

When I attempt to run the experiment, I get an error return and the experiment fails to start:

```
File "C:\Users\r02mj20\AppData\Local\PsychoPy3\lib\site-packages\psychopy\visual\image.py", line 238, in __del__ 
File "C:\Users\r02mj20\AppData\Local\PsychoPy3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\lib.py", line 97, in errcheck
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with pyglet not liking the idea of there being 100 rectangles all at once (side note: the script works fine if *range*(1)). If anyone has any suggestions for how I might fix or work around this problem, I'd be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 0):

i don't see any problem with this idea, except you better use `visual.Line` instead of Rect, and your units of measure are not described; the key to preserving video memory is `BufferImageStim`, btw

```
from psychopy import visual, core, event, monitors
from psychopy.iohub.client import launchHubServer

import random
import numpy as np

MU = 315; SIGMA = 15
num_lines = 100

io = launchHubServer(iohub_config_name='iohub_config.yaml')
display = io.devices.display
mon = monitors.Monitor(name = display.getPsychopyMonitorName())

win = visual.Window([640, 480], units='pix', viewScale = 1.0,
                    monitor = mon, winType='pyglet',
                    fullScr = False, waitBlanking = True, useFBO = True, useLights = False,
                    allowStencil=False, allowGui = True,
                    screen = display.getIndex(), colorSpace = 'rgb255', color = [128,128,128],
                    name = 'my_win01')

rects = []
lines_hpos = np.random.uniform(-0.49, 0.49, num_lines)
for i in range(num_lines):
    line_rect = visual.Rect(win=win, size=(0.001, 1.0), units='norm',
                            pos=(0,0), lineWidth=1, lineColor=[1,1,1], fillColor=[1,1,1], opacity=1, depth=-2.0,
                            name='lines_rect', interpolate=True, autoLog=False, autoDraw=False)
    line_rect.pos = [lines_hpos[i], np.random.uniform(-0.49,0.49)]
    line_rect.ori = random.gauss(MU, SIGMA)
    rects.append(line_rect)

rect_buffer = visual.BufferImageStim(win, buffer='back', stim=rects, sqPower2=False, interpolate=False, name='rect-buffer', autoLog=True)
rect_buffer.draw()
win.flip()

event.waitKeys()
```

[image]